# How can i compare two time variables in Php

Tags: php, android

I have  two time variables time1 and time2 both of string type and with the format (yyyy:mm:dd HH:mm:ss). I need to compare them to get if:

1. time1 = time2
2. time1 <  time2 or time2 < time1
3. time1 > time2  or time2 > time1
4. And when using the combination of the '='         and either '<'or '>'

Any help will be really appreciated.
Am learning android together with php while doing a project for my Semester

Answer (score 1):

### strtotime() function can be helpful

> Check out the documentation here [for strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
$str1 = "2016:4:9";
$str2 = "2016:1:1";
$time1 = strtotime($str1);
$time2 = strtotime($str2);

if ($time1 > $time2) { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$date1 = new DateTime("now");
$date2 = new DateTime("tomorrow");

var_dump($date1 == $date2);
var_dump($date1 < $date2);
var_dump($date1 > $date2);


// Output
bool(false)
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

More...

```
$dateA = '2008-03-01 13:34'; 
$dateB = '2007-04-14 15:23'; 
if(strtotime($dateA) > strtotime($dateB)){ 
    // ...
}
```